# How update camel property value?

Tags: properties, routes

I have a property in my route.I want to change value of this property in choice/when. How can I do this in my route?

```xml
<route>
    <setProperty propertyName="UpdateORInsert">
        <constant>INSERT</constant>
    </setProperty>

    <choice>
    <when>
       ------Change value of UpdateORInsert-------
    </when>
    </choice>

</route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It can be done using simple component in your route inside `when`:

    <route>
        <setProperty propertyName="UpdateORInsert">
            <constant>INSERT</constant>
        </setProperty>
        <choice>
        <when>
          <simple>${Yourspecificcondition}</simple>
         <setProperty propertyName="UpdateORInsert">
            <constant>UPDATE</constant>
        </setProperty>
        </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
```